# Get all users specific sessions from firebase to display in my listbox

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm currently using VS2017, ASP.NET webform. I'm making a Listbox where it displays will display all users session (finding a specific session like ["comment"] only for all users to display). I'm also using Firesharp to connect to my webform to Firebase. Is there any way to do it using for loop? Thanks!